# Validating firstname and lastname in Arabic

Tags: ios, ios4, uitextfield, multilingual

In my application A have support for Arabic. For registration we have Firstname, Lastname, email id and Password.

I am validating the first name and last name as below

```
-(BOOL)isValidDisplayName {
    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];

    if ([self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {

        return NO;
    }

    if ([self length] < 3) {

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}

-(BOOL)isValidLastName {
    NSCharacterSet * set = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLKMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"] invertedSet];

    if ([self rangeOfCharacterFromSet:set].location != NSNotFound) {

        return NO;
    }

    if ([self length] < 1) {

        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

The above validation works for English. So how should I validate the Arabic input for firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check that both fields contain only alphabetic characters then probably the thing to test against is the inversion of [`[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCharacterSet_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSCharacterSet/letterCharacterSet) rather than of your own hardcoding of the letter character set but limited to the English alphabet.